# How can i change the TextView from a layout which is used by different fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to reproduce an app like this one:http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html so the fragments will have a TextView and I'm trying to use the same layout for all fragments and just change the Text from TextView.(1,2,3,4,5) but when I setText  I got a crash.

```
package com.example.msixthapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class ScreenSlidePagerActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private Fragment a[] = new Fragment [10];
private static final int NUM_PAGES=5;
public static TextView txt;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_slide_pager);
    
    viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    
    for(int i=0;i<NUM_PAGES;i++){
    a[i]= new  ScreenSlidePageFragmen();    
    
    }   
}

@Override
 public void onBackPressed(){
       if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
            // If the user is currently looking at the first step, allow the    system to handle the
            // Back button. This calls finish() on this activity and pops the back stack.
            super.onBackPressed();
        } else {
            // Otherwise, select the previous step.
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
        }
}

private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {     
        return ScreenSlidePageFragmen.create(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }
}
}
```

---

```
package com.example.msixthapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * A simple {@link android.support.v4.app.Fragment} subclass.
* 
*/
public class ScreenSlidePageFragmen extends Fragment {
public static String ARG_PAGE="page";
private int mPageNumber;
public ScreenSlidePageFragmen() {
    // Required empty public constructor
    
}
   public static ScreenSlidePageFragmen create(int pageNumber) {
     ScreenSlidePageFragmen fragmen = new ScreenSlidePageFragmen();
     Bundle args = new Bundle();
     args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, pageNumber);
     fragmen.setArguments(args);
        return fragmen;
    }
   @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      mPageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
   }

   @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_page, container,false);
    TextView txt = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.cont);
//  txt.setText(mPageNumber+1);
//  ((TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.content)).setText(mPageNumber+1);
    TextView txte = new TextView(null);
    txte.setText(mPageNumber);
    rootView.addView(txte);
    
    return rootView;
}

}
```

And the Layouts

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".ScreenSlidePagerActivity" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/container"
tools:context=".ScreenSlidePageFragmen" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cont"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:text="tst"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update Here**

```
@Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_page, container,false);
    TextView txt = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.cont);
//  txt.setText(mPageNumber+1);
//  ((TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.content)).setText(mPageNumber+1);
    TextView txte = new TextView(getActivity());
    txte.setText(mPageNumber);
    rootView.addView(txte);

    return rootView;
}
```